# Accidentally installed phpmyadmin as root user

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, yii, phpmyadmin

While trying to install phpmyadmin, I accidentally installed it as a root user.

Beginning of the story, I was editing the httpd.conf file of Apache. To avoid permission issues while running some commands, i did `sudo su -` on the terminal. Thereafter without exiting from root user, I installed phpmyadmin using the following commands

```
cd /Library/WebServer/Documents/
tar -xvf ~/Downloads/phpMyAdmin-3.5.2.2-english.tar.gz
mv phpMyAdmin-3.5.2.2-english/ phpmyadmin
cd phpmyadmin
mv config.sample.inc.php config.inc.php
```

But now when I try to install yii at `/Library/WebServer/Documents/`, i get the following error

```
PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException

mkdir(): Permission denied
```

Is there any way I can remove the root user privilege from phpmyadmin without uninstalling?

Operating system: OS MAC Mavericks

Comment: Probably just a permission error? Do `ls -l` to see who owns and what permissions are on phpmyadmin directory and perhaps to a chmod or chown to relax them somewhat...

Comment: @PeterBowers The `ls -l` command at phpmyadmin folder shows the following: `drwxrwxrwx@ 112 root        wheel   3808 Feb 28 14:03 phpmyadmin`

Comment: What are your permissions for Documents?

Comment: @PeterBowers: You are right. All the permissions are for root. 
`drwxr-xr-x  2 root        wheel       68 Dec 11  2013 CGI-Executables`
`drwxr-xr-x  9 root        wheel      306 Mar  1 02:03 Documents`
`-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 cborkotoky  wheel  1800576 Feb 28 23:25 Webserver_Documents alias`
`drwxr-xr-x  3 root        wheel      102 Dec 11  2013 share`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to this problem, just simple...
All works with rights on folders in Yii.

Applied the chmod command recursively across yii/ directory. The following is the command snippet for reference:

```
Editors-Mac:Documents cborkotoky$ chmod -R 777 yii
Editors-Mac:Documents cborkotoky$ pwd
/Library/WebServer/Documents
Editors-Mac:Documents cborkotoky$ ls -l
total 80

-rw-r--r--    1 cborkotoky  wheel   3726 Dec 11  2013 PoweredByMacOSX.gif
-rw-r--r--    1 cborkotoky  wheel  31958 Dec 11  2013 PoweredByMacOSXLarge.gif
drwxr-xr-x    5 cborkotoky  wheel    170 Feb 28 23:18 firstProject
-rw-r--r--    1 cborkotoky  wheel     44 Jun 28  2014 index.html.en
drwxrwxrwx@ 112 cborkotoky  wheel   3808 Feb 28 14:03 phpmyadmin
-rw-r--r--    1 cborkotoky  wheel     23 Feb 26 17:59 test.php
drwxrwxrwx    4 cborkotoky  wheel    136 Mar  1 02:03 yii
```

Comment: I realize that this is on your personal Mac and just for development, so this is probably not a big deal, but in general, chmod 777 is something to be very careful with.  It makes it easy for small security problems to multiply.  After you get it working you might experiment with removing some of the excess permissions.  For example, chmod -R o-wx {dirname} will remove write and execute permissions  for anyone who isn't the owner or group.

Comment: @ratsbane: Appreciate the advice. Will definitely keep a note.

Answer (score 0):

[chown with the -R flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown) (recursive) is probably what you want.  (The following may not apply exactly to your circumstances so please consider it carefully before running).

Of course, replace {YourUsername} with your actual username.  The commands below just change the owner of the files and not the group.  If you need to change the group name also, the new name goes after the colon:

```
cd /Library/WebServer/Documents/
chown -R {YourUsername}: phpmyadmin
```

Comment: I ran the command `chown -R cborkotoky Documents`. It did change the owner from root to myself. I restarted apache but still problem persists.